# Gradle in Ubuntu for Launchpad

Tags: application-development, java, launchpad, gradle

It appears that Ubuntu doesn't have new versions of Gradle in their repositories for some reason. I need it for a project that will be build by Launchpad.

What should I do about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently its possible to add a PPA as a dependency to a PPA and thus including Gradle.

https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA/BuildingASourcePackage#Dependencies

Answer (score 86):

> Gradle requires a Java JDK to be installed. Gradle requires a JDK 1.5
>   or higher. Gradle ships with its own Groovy library, therefore no
>   Groovy needs to be installed. Any existing Groovy installation is
>   ignored by Gradle.
>
> Gradle uses whichever JDK it finds in your path (to check, use java
>   -version). Alternatively, you can set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to point to the install directory of the desired JDK.

So make sure that you have Java JDK installed, then head to [Gradle's Website](http://www.gradle.org/installation) to download Gradle, and any other info that you may need.

Or, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gradle
```

<sup>Source:Gradle</sup>

Comment: Well I could use that on my local machine but would that work on Launchpad? How would I tell it to download Gradle before starting the build.

Comment: I don't think that you can do that.  I think that you need to build locally, and then add to Launchpad.

Comment: Why did you unaccept? :)

Comment: Because that would not work on Launchpad. In Launchpad you're able to add a PPA for build dependencies. So I added it and specified it as a build dependency on my package. I've added that as a answer to this question so others can see it too.

Comment: where is gradle home after running this commands?

Comment: @nazar_art Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495474/intellij-cannot-find-gradle-home-location

Comment: It seems the gradle home is then /usr/share/gradle

Comment: I have a problem: "gradle is already the newest version."

Comment: @IgorG. What is the problem?

Comment: @Mitch I cannot install gradle, even though my system says that gradle is newest version!

Comment: Why do you want to install, if its already installed, and its at the newest version?

Answer (score 30):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
```

This is correct answer, but before make `sudo apt-get install gradle`, do:

```
sudo apt-cache search gradle
```

and next install latest version from new repo. In my case it:

```
sudo apt-get install gradle-1.9
```

it work's! (if you don't tell, what version you need, it install gradle(1.4) from main repo, and error will be with you...).

Comment: But I get a message: "gradle-1.9 is already the latest version".  Hence it doesn't let me install gradle.

Comment: Gradle is installed to `/usr/lib/gradle/{your-version}`

Answer (score 2):

**gradlew**, the Gradle Wrapper, seems to be the best method: https://docs.gradle.org/2.11/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

It is a script generated by Gradle which can automatically:

- download a required Gradle version if missing
- use it when required

You will then always use `./gradlew command` from the root of the project instead of your system's `gradle`.

How to generate the wrapper is explained on the docs and at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25769536/how-when-to-generate-gradle-wrapper-files

Answer (score 1):

**sdkman**

I faced a similar issue recently where i needed gradle just for one project:
Using apt wasn't very appealing as that meant tons of extra dependencies which i would certainly forget to uninstall afterwards. Also i needed a fairly recent gradle build.

I went with [sdkman](http://sdkman.io) package manager instead which is pretty neat for java development:
You get bleeding edge versions of packages installed directly to your home directory without interfering with ubuntu system-wide setup. After i'm done i can just delete the user i created for the task and everything is back as before.

To install sdkman and gradle:

```
$ curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
Open new terminal  
$ sdk install gradle
```