# How to update maven 3.0.4 - 3.1.1

Tags: upgrade, software-installation, maven-3

First of all am new to Ubuntu as well as Maven. Does anyone know how to update maven. My current version of maven is 3.0.4. I would like to update it to 3.1.1 which is the latest version. I tried

```
sudo apt-get update maven
```

but this didn't help much. Any suggestion. Am using maven for first time. Also how to install

> apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz

I know there is an command like

> sudo apt-get install maven

but it will download maven and then install it.. Since I may need to install maven on a few systems downloading it each time won't be a better option for us. So I am looking forward answer for two questions

1. How to update installed maven
2. How to install downloaded package of maven apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradle in Ubuntu for Launchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328178/gradle-in-ubuntu-for-launchpad)

Comment: Easiest is probably to [use sdkman](https://askubuntu.com/a/916662/119231).

Answer (score 57):

To upgrade single package in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install maven
```

To Install downloaded package of maven apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://apache.mirrors.timporter.net/maven/maven-3/3.1.1/binaries/apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz

sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/apache-maven
sudo mv apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz /usr/local/apache-maven
cd /usr/local/apache-maven
sudo tar -xzvf apache-maven-3.1.1-bin.tar.gz
```

Edit  ~/.profile with `gedit ~/.profile` and add these four lines:

> ```
> export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
> export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
> export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m"
> export PATH=$M2:$PATH
> ```

don't forget to execute following command to have the update without restarting the machine

```
 source ~/.profile
```

Comment: is ' sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install maven ' upgrade maven to latest version 3.1.1 coz i tried it and still its 3.0.4

Comment: update your package list first with sudo apt-get update

Comment: if it doesn't work, try with wget

Comment: i tried sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get --only-upgrade install maven.. as suja's comment says, it does not update my maven to 3.1.1. it is still 3.0.4

Comment: @MadhavanKumar that's because the last version published in `apt` is `3.0.4`. You can always check that with `sudo apt-get update` to refresh your local cache; then `apt-cache search maven` and finally `apt-cache showpkg <name-of-the-package>` to see the current version.

Comment: Does anyone know if Apache is going to update Maven on the Ubuntu repos? The package they host on the default repos still has bugs and it's been over a year.

Comment: This answer is now dated.  The simplest and cleanest solution is the newer answer by Janek Bogucki below.

Comment: Always mention your Ubuntu version!! 14.04 still has 3.0.x, 16.04 has 3.3.x (ight now)

Comment: The methodology is NOT outdated, only the maven version. Simply change 3.1.1 to the current version, and it works fine. I successfully did that with maven 3.3.9

Answer (score 20):

On the basis the original question asked about the latest version of Maven this PPA provides a backport from `wily` to `trusty` for Maven 3.3.9

https://launchpad.net/~andrei-pozolotin/+archive/ubuntu/maven3

Instructions to use this PPA are copied from the link above.

> ```
> sudo apt-get purge maven maven2 maven3
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrei-pozolotin/maven3
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install maven3
> ```

This worked fine for me on `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS`. The installed command was `mvn` without any need to add a symlink.

```
$ mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T16:41:47+00:00)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven3
Java version: 1.8.0_66, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-33-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: The simplest and cleanest solution, no symbolic links to create. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

There is a PPA for maven with 3.1 at https://launchpad.net/~natecarlson/+archive/maven3

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:natecarlson/maven3
```

The only problem is that the command-line tool from the PPA is maven3, which is going to break any scripts calling mvn.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/maven3 /usr/bin/mvn
```

Comment: it was /usr/bin/mvn3 in my case...

Comment: This solution looks like good, but doesn't work with recent versions of Ubuntu, like 14.04.

Comment: outdated: latest version on ~natecarlson is 3.2.1, while latest version of maven is 3.2.5

Comment: There's a PPA for Utopic at: https://launchpad.net/~vkorenev/+archive/ubuntu/maven3

Comment: Also, a variation on the linking is to use update-alternatives: `sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/mvn" "mvn" "/usr/share/maven3/bin/mvn" 1` then switch with `sudo update-alternatives --config mvn`

Comment: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu/dists/utopic/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

Comment: @ZiglioNZ: That PPA only works for Lucid - Precise and is outdated even if you are running one of those versions.

Comment: Thank you, I used http://ppa.launchpad.net/vkorenev/maven3/ubuntu

Comment: The natecarleson/maven3 is out of date and hasn't been updated for 80+ weeks now.

Comment: It is worth noting that although a PPA might not support an older version of Ubuntu, that doesn't mean the packages won't work. For example, I just downloaded Maven 3.3.9 from https://launchpad.net/~andrei-pozolotin/+archive/ubuntu/maven3 and installed it on Ubuntu 12.04 using `dpkg` and it is working just fine.

Answer (score 6):

To install mvn3 on Ubuntu 14.04, run:

```
sudo apt-get purge maven maven2 maven3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:andrei-pozolotin/maven3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install maven3
```

To make a symbolic link, run:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/maven3/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

Reference: https://launchpad.net/~andrei-pozolotin/+archive/ubuntu/maven3

Comment: This is probably the more contemporary solution to use. Many thanks.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package maven3

Comment: Great answer, I've been trying to make this work all day, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found this guide worked best for Ubuntu 14.04 to upgrade maven to 3.2.1
http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-apache-maven-3-2-1-on-ubuntu-14-04-linux-mint-17-and-their-derivative-systems/

First, remove the previous mavens of maven, do:

```
sudo apt-get remove maven*
```

Install Maven 3:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi

wget http://ppa.launchpad.net/natecarlson/maven3/ubuntu/pool/main/m/maven3/maven3_3.2.1-0~ppa1_all.deb

sudo gdebi maven3_3.2.1-0~ppa1_all.deb
```

Symlink it, for an easier usage:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/maven3/bin/mvn /usr/bin/maven
```

Comment: it would be much better using the PPA repository as is, not downloading debs to install them manually. see @david-baucum answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/420281/how-to-update-maven-3-0-4-3-1-1#answer-454401

Comment: same way you can download deb for Maven 3.3.9 from http://ppa.launchpad.net/andrei-pozolotin/maven3/ubuntu/pool/main/m/maven3/maven3_3.3.9-001_all.deb

Answer (score 3):

Tried the instructions here and the ones on apache.org. What ultimately fixed it was creating a symbolic link for maven:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.2.1/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not comfortable with a PPA (***personal*** package archive) where you have no assurance of the provenance this is an alternative.

*From a security perspective if you don't know where it came from don't install it.*

In my [article](https://www.tomred.net/devops/install-the-latest-version-of-maven-on-linux.html) I retrieve the latest file from apache which is a known and trusted source. You can get the latest version

```
#identify the latest version of maven
    latest=$(curl http://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/ | tac | sed -ne 's/[^0-9]*\(\([0-9]\.\)\{0,3\}[0-9]\).*/\1/p' | head -1)
#download it
    wget http://www-us.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/$latest/binaries/apache-maven-$latest-bin.tar.gz
```

then install it from

```
#Unpack it
    sudo tar -zxf apache-maven-$latest-bin.tar.gz -C /usr/local/
#create a sym link to it
    sudo ln -s /usr/local/apache-maven-$latest/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn
```

as outlined in the link above and my post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33616867/can-not-install-mvn-3-3-3-on-ubuntu-14-04/43558580#43558580)

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.

Comment: @DavidPostill fair enough. But these are the questions that I searched and didn't find a useful answer on that is why I linked them together. Maybe when I build the reps I will do the duplicate but in the mean time I will raise a flag. Thanks for the advise.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest maven from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

```
wget http://apache-mirror.rbc.ru/pub/apache/maven/maven-3/3.2.2/binaries/apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz
tar -zxf apache-maven-3.2.2-bin.tar.gz /tmp/
ln -s /tmp/apache-maven-3.2.2/bin/mvn /usr/local/bin/mvn
```

Check with

```
$ mvn -v
```

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded on mac and it was pretty easy.
Get the maven from https://maven.apache.org/install.html
Just add the maven~/bin to the PATH and update the JAVA_HOME.
Then try out mvn -v to show the versions